# if statement is being executed even when the condition is false

Tags: jquery, if-statement

while executing the code only if statements are being executed even when the condition is false.

I tried DEBUGGING and the condition i'm giving is definitely giving a false back but not sure why

```
 if (
    $("#ship-to-different-address-checkbox").length != 0 &&
    $(".shipping_address").length == 0
  ) {
    postcode = $("#shipping_postcode").val();
  } else {
    postcode = $("#billing_postcode").val();
  }
```

And I also tried

```
     if (
        $("#ship-to-different-address-checkbox").length != 0 &&
        $(".shipping_address").is(":visible")
      ) {
        postcode = $("#shipping_postcode").val();
      } else {
        postcode = $("#billing_postcode").val();
      }
```

no matter what it is going to the if statement. Could anyone please help me with this?

Comment: If statements will only ever trigger when the condition is `true`. You'll probably find that `#ship-to-different-address-checkbox` is `undefined` rather than `0`, as checkboxes don't have a `.length`.

Comment: @ObsidianAge doesn't jQuery wrapped object always have a `.length` property?

Comment: No it is not, your conditions are not what you think they are. Your question should be I can't figure out why this condition is true.